# Flutter bluetooth.It doesn't give me real devices

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

Hi everybody I'm trying to use flutter_blue in my app.For this ı use this github project.https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/example/lib/widgets.dart. However when ı run this in my emulator it gives me 2 devices which are gDevice-beacon it didn't give me real devices.How can ı solve this.

Comment: Have you added required permissions in Manifest file? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: yes this is my Manifest file.Have a look please: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.water_irrigation">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application

Comment: Try running it in real device as suggested by @CoolNa

Answer (score 1):

You must run your app in your real phone.How can you think your emulator can show real device when your turn on bluetooth :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in build.gradle file in app:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false    // this line
            minifyEnabled false       // this line
        }
    }
```

You can also try building the apk by :

```
flutter build apk --no-shrink
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33874009)